# Error setting up simple server with middleware on node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am reasonably new to node express and am trying to set up a simple server with middleware to handle routing.
The error I'm getting is `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`
The error is because of the `app.get('/', require(routes));` line. Does anyone know what I need to put here as a middleware function?

```
//server.js
http = require('http');
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let host = '127.0.0.1';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = './api/routes/positions';

app.use('/', require(routes));

http.createServer(app).listen(port);
console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);

//#########################
//positions.js
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
    message: "hello from server"
    });
});

module.exports.router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting the module in wrong way from `positions.js` file.

you need to write

```
module.exports = router
```

instead of,

```
module.exports.router
```

What you have written will bind a new key `router` to `exports` object, but haven't assigned any value to it and hence it goes back to default the empty object `{}`.

Now express was expecting a function but got object and hence the error. You can verify it by checking the `require(routes)` in `server.js` file.

#### Update (advice)

Please study this formatted version of your code.

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const routes = require('./api/routes/positions');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const host = '127.0.0.1';

const app = express();

app.use('/', routes);

http.createServer(app).listen(port);
console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

If you want to read more project, you can read this [boilerplate](https://github.com/raghavgarg1257/nodejs-mysql-boilerplate) written by me. It's bit old, but may serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('ag:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3002');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: use these commands in command prompt .         1.express --hbs     2. npm  install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
     //server.js
        let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
        let host = '127.0.0.1';
        var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var routes = require('./api/routes/positions');

    http.createServer(app).listen(port);
    console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);

    //#########################
    //positions.js
    const express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    router.use('/', routes);
   app.use('/', routes);
    router.get('/', (err, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(200).json({
        message: "hello from server"
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you written module.exports in middle ware file and export your object

Comment: You have assign middle ware to your app instead of this you need to assign it in your router object, i have done change in code please check it